Appwrite Exception: 404 Error when trying to list documents in Kotlin
I have the following problem and I cannot solve it although I have already searched through the Internet.
I set up my own Appwrite server locally with a project called RunningTracker.
Then I created a collection also called RunningTracker with some Documents.
Afterwards I tried to get all documents with Kotlin.
The values for PROJECT_ID and ENDPOINT were taken from my local Appwrite server, so they must be okay.
The values for listDocuments like databaseID, I do not know where to find that.
So, I always get the following error message, however, a connection to the server is possible as I can see in the WebGUI.
<main data-ls-router data-first-from-server="true" data-acl data-analytics-pageview>
        <section class="zone large margin-top padding">
            <h1 class="margin-bottom">Error 404</h1>
            <p>Not Found</p> <small>Error ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</small>
        </section>
    </main>

This is my source code.
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        initObjects()
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch { withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { callGetDatabases() }}
    }

private fun initObjects() {
    client = Client(this)
        .setEndpoint(ENDPOINT)
        .setProject(PROJECT_ID)
        .setSelfSigned(status = true)

    account = Account(client)

    val realtime = Realtime(client)
    realtime.subscribe("\"databases.default.collections.movies.documents.lion-king.create\",\n" +
            "      \"databases.*.collections.*.documents.*.create\",\n" +
            "      \"databases.default.collections.*.documents.lion-king.create\",\n" +
            "      \"databases.*.collections.*.documents.lion-king.create\",\n" +
            "      \"databases.*.collections.movies.documents.lion-king.create\",\n" +
            "      \"databases.default.collections.movies.documents.*.create\",\n" +
            "      \"databases.*.collections.movies.documents.*.create\",\n" +
            "      \"databases.default.collections.*.documents.*.create\",\n" +
            "      \"databases.default.collections.movies.documents.lion-king\",\n" +
            "      \"databases.*.collections.*.documents.*\",\n" +
            "      \"databases.default.collections.*.documents.lion-king\",\n" +
            "      \"databases.*.collections.*.documents.lion-king\",\n" +
            "      \"databases.*.collections.movies.documents.lion-king\",\n" +
            "      \"databases.default.collections.movies.documents.*\",\n" +
            "      \"databases.*.collections.movies.documents.*\",\n" +
            "      \"databases.default.collections.*.documents.*\",\n" +
            "      \"databases.default.collections.movies\",\n" +
            "      \"databases.*.collections.*\",\n" +
            "      \"databases.default.collections.*\",\n" +
            "      \"databases.*.collections.movies\",\n" +
            "      \"databases.*.collections.*.documents.*.update\",\n" +
            "      \"databases.default\",\n" +
            "      \"databases.*\"", "files.*") {
        print(it.toString())
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "DISPLAY: " + it.payload.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    suspend fun callGetDatabases() {
        val databases = Databases(client)
        try {
            databases.listDocuments("", "COLLECTION ID")
        } catch (e: AppwriteException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val PROJECT_ID = "SOME_PROJECT_ID"
        private const val ENDPOINT = "https://192.168.0.178/v1"
    }
}

Maybe, someone can help me to figure out the problem!
Thanks in advance.
